# Should looper pedal come before or after reverb pedal?

Tags: effects-pedal

I have a reverb effects pedal connected to my audio interface. I want to throw in a looper. Should it be:
looper -> reverb -> audio interface
reverb -> looper -> audio interface

or maybe it should come after the whole thing?
reverb -> audio interface -> loop pedal
(or maybe you shouldn't connect anything after an audio interface apart from monitors?)

Answer (score 7):

If the reverb is before the loop, I would expect the reverberating sound could be cut off in cases where reverb is long and loop is short. That might result it some artificial sound in terms of reverb suggesting a physical room/space. Putting reverb last should more naturally mimic a room/space.

Comment: last as in after the audio interface, or before it?

Comment: last in the effects chain before going into the interface

Comment: but definitely wait for other answers, I'm a novice when it comes to gear.

Answer (score 4):

The looper will record exactly what you want to play into it. So if you want that particular instrument to have reverb, put it before. If you're building up on a recording, adding other parts, it will depend on whether you want *everything* to be 'reverbed' after - which is common practice - in which case, put it after. There is no right or wrong, and trial and error, as in so many things, will give you the results (or not) that *you* are searching for.